# SPRING 3 MVC - MySQL JDBC DataBase Connection Configuration

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc

Lost in the multitude of  Java API's and XML configuration.

I am trying to create an app with the Spring MVC but struggling with the XML configuration.

I want to be able to connect to a mysql database... but I am struggling to find any concise way of how to do it.  I do not want to use  Hibernate or any additional frameworks, the JDBC will be adequate on it's own.

I would just like to be able to create a database connection and access to a String variable that can change the query as necessary.  I think the problem lies within the xml configuration, but I may be wrong.

I have pasted the details shown below in the application-context.xml file, but the server cannot be built unless I remove them.  I am not sure if I am missing something simple!

```
<bean id="JdbcDao" class="com.bcash.DbAccess.JdbcDao">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>      

<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
      p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      p:url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name"
      p:username="root"
      p:password=""
      destroy-method="close" />
```

This is the associated class that I wrote for the xml declaration

```
package com.bcash.DbAccess;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

public class JdbcDao {

private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
protected String query = "INSERT INTO    user('username','email','password','access_level') VALUES ('admin','test@test.com','testPassWord','admin')";


public void insertUser(){

    try{
        jdbcTemplate.update(query);

    } catch(DataAccessException e){

       String error =  e.getMessage();
       System.out.println(error);

    }

}

}
```

The only error that I get is that the server could not be deployed on line 726 of the ant build script

```
<target if="netbeans.home" name="-run-deploy-nb">
    <nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
</target>
```

Although, I am okay with PHP, I am a little confused as I am fairly new to Java.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not clear what the problem is--you're saying you can't build the project unless you remove the datasource XML config, but you get no message regarding it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know that I really follow the question you are asking about the build, but looking at the code and how you have things setup I do see one thing that looks like a problem. It looks like you never instantiate your `JdbcTemplate` and associate it with the dataSource.

You should create your JdbcTemplate instance as a bean like this:

```
  <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource">
      <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
  </bean>
```

Then make sure you have a set method for your `jdbcTemplate` variable and pass the reference to the template into your bean instead of the dataSource.

```
<bean id="JdbcDao" class="com.bcash.DbAccess.JdbcDao">
    <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate"/>
</bean>
```

Doing this your JdbcTemplate will have a reference to your dataSource and you should then be able to perform queries.

Comment: So, was that the only thing preventing deployment then?  I've never used `nbdeploy` before so I wasn't sure if that would be the cause.

Comment: Yes that was the only thing that was stopping the deployment.. managed to fix it by moving the bean details into the dispatcher-servlet.xml file and it worked fine!